# How to fetch the particular column from an existing table database created in 000webhost server using php in to my android app

Tags: c#, php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xamarin.android

I have a spinner in my xamarin android app as shown

[image]

if I select "Bachelorsdegree" from the dropdown list of the spinner it should retrive the data regarding bachlorsdegree from the database which is already created in the 000webhost server as shown below

[image]

> The php code which i tried and for this but i am getting the result as null

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","id11188796_universitylist");
if(!$con){
    echo "Not Connected";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Connected successfully";
    }
$sql="SELECT * FROM Universities";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

if($result)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $flag[]= $row;
    }
    print(json_encode($flag));
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Can you suggest something thanks

Comment: You should see if there's any errors being outputted from MySQL; `print_r(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: I checked my connection it is showing connected successfully I think I failed in extracting the data from my table  (I am doing it in c# xamarin.android)

Comment: When you execute the PHP on your server, do you get the intended json result? If it's an issue with your c# then you need to post some of that code rather than the PHP mysql stuff

Comment: Where is your problem at? Why is it tagged phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @Dharman in Downloader.cs  in ":OnPostExecute" method I getting result is null

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.